# Asterisk: Outbound and Inbound call at the same time

Tags: asynchronous, centos, asterisk, synchronous, pbx

I am looking this use case scenario for Asterisk. I am using v 1.8 running a Centos 6.4 Linux distribution.

1.An outbound call is initiated via Asterisk

2.Both the internal extension as well as the outbound call-phone starts to ring.

1. The first person to pick up (either the internal extension or outbound call-phone) will

   hear the a pre recorded message to hold as the call is being connected to the other user

i.e: If outbound call-phone picks up first then he will be asked to hold the line while the call is being connected to internal-phone user.

Any inputs?

Comment: I'd like to know what is the reason for the negative vote...

Comment: @olivecoder this question is [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @jgb: it don't seems off topic to me. It is about the method to implement an use case over a very specific software platform, but, at the end of the day, it is just about algorithms and APIs. So I am not sure. Please could you explain the reasons why it is off topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is almost the same but a little different:

- Setup a dynamic meetme room changing the only-person message to "please hold..."
- Setup booth calls at same time to destination numbers and set the originate command application parameter as meetme

Comment: Thanks oliver! Yes i will be using this idea. Just a simple follow up to this. I am v1.8 can i use ConfBridge instead of MeetMe?

Comment: Yes, sure. PS: I see you are a new user, so please upvote if you think that is a useful answer. You can read more about votes in: http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: While you can use ConfBridge in 1.8, it is radically different than ConfBridge in 10+. We made some major improvements (and changes) to ConfBridge in Asterisk 10, such that if you want to use ConfBridge, you really should be using Asterisk 10+. In Asterisk 1.8, you're probably better off using MeetMe.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 calls

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out

After connect use bridge command or conference room.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+MeetMe